# Network wide feed not updating

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app, android-app-feed

My feed hasn't updated for over a month. I can go to a specific site and see latest questions, but if I go to Hamburger Menu => Feed, I'm stuck in the past.

I have version 1.0.60 of the Stack Exchange App, and am on Android Lollipop 5.0.2.  It might have broken when I updated my OS from Kit Kat, but I'm not sure of the timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My phone app updated to version 1.0.62  within the past day, and it appears to be working now. I presume the latest update resolved this issue.